# Density is zero in circular potential

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential, gauss-law

Is it true that the density is zero in a circular potential $$\Phi = \frac{-GM}{r}?$$ Using the Laplacian, it yields a value of zero for $\rho$.

Comment: Hint:  what to do about the case $r=0$?

Comment: Why do you think this is the case? Please explain what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the Laplacian, you'll find $0$ everywhere **BUT** $r=0$. It is possible to prove that:

$\Delta \frac {1}{r} = -4\pi\delta^3(\mathbf{r})$

Putting all together you'll find $\rho = M\delta^3(\mathbf{r})$ that is the "density" for a point-like object in $\mathbf{r}=0$ with mass $M$ that is exactly what creates that central $1/r$ potential.